# PowerShell check files: foreach loop on failure

Tags: powershell

I am using PowerShell copy files to multiple locations, then do a check after `copy` done, I want to send a message on failure if one or more files does not exist on one of the destinations.

```
$SRCDIR1 = "C:\temp\Copy\00_S"
$DST = "C:\temp\Copy\01_D","C:\temp\Copy\02_D","C:\temp\Copy\03_D"

$File_list = Get-ChildItem -Path $SRCDIR1\*.xml

$DST | %{ Copy-Item $SRCDIR1\*.xml -Destination $_ }

Foreach ($item in $File_list) {   
   If (Test-Path $DST ) {    
         Write-Host $item exists in $DST    
   }
   else {    
         Write-Host $item DOES NOT exists in $DST    
   }        
}
```

It works when all files are in all destinations, but if I delete different files from different destinations testing "write-host if not exist", it still "write-host" everything exists.

On failure, i want it "write-host" which file doest not exist on which destination separately. How can I modify the code?

**Update** made it working. has to be loop in loop....

```
$FileList = Get-ChildItem -Path $SRCDIR1\*.xml | Select -ExpandProperty Name

Foreach ($item in $FileList){


  $DST | 

    % {if (Test-Path ($_ + "\" +  "$item")){

        write-host $item exist in $_ -ForegroundColor Green

        }else{
            write-host $item does not exist in $_ -ForegroundColor Red  

        }

       }

    }
```

Comment: Please format your code

Answer (score 0):

Your `$DST` is an Array of Strings and this is the *"problem"*, as `Test-Path` will return one boolean value for each path in that array:

```
PS> $DST = "C:\temp\Copy\01_D","C:\temp\Copy\02_D","C:\temp\Copy\03_D"
PS> Test-Path $DST
True
True
False
```

Which means `if(Test-Path $DST)` will be the same as `if(@($true, $true, $false))`. Let's see how they are evaluated:

```
PS> if ($false) {"HA!"} else {"Ney"}
Ney
PS> if (@($false, $false)) {"HA!"} else {"Ney"}
HA!
```

As you can see, `if ($variable)` evaluates to `$true`, when `$variable` is any non-null value which is not `$false`, so even `@($false, $false, $false)` will evaluate to `$true`.

Don't check `$DST`, instead check for `$item`'s existence:

```
if (Test-Path $item) {
    Write-Host $item exists in $DST
}
```

Comment: Do I need to specify the location where `$item` to check from? like `$DST\$item` ? I my case, in different destinations, it may missing different files, how can it prompt me separately for individual file missing in different destinations?

Comment: No, but I missed something. Edited. `$item.FullName` gives you the absolute path.

Comment: This is what I tested, I left different files in 3 destinations and run the script again, `Test-Path $item.FullName` I got the same result, all files from source exist in all 3 destinations.

Comment: Ok, I executed your code. How exactly are the file names in the xml file stored? It seems like you have to concatenate them like `$DST + $item`